# Правильно ли здесь расставлены запятые

Tags: запятая

Здравствуйте! Правильно ли здесь расставлены запятые?

"Делается все, чтобы через взвинчивание напряженности вокруг межнациональных отношений, в связи с разгромом и т.д., сорвать поездку."

Answer (score 2):

По крайней мере, допустимо.

http://www.licey.net/russian/syntax/r1_2_5_2     
 Обстоятельства причины с предлогами и предложными сочетаниями благодаря, в связи с, вследствие, ввиду, за неимением, за отсутствием, согласно, в силу,  по причине, по случаю и др. МОГУТ обособляться (можно заменить придаточным предложением с союзом так как), а могут не обособляться,на выбор автора, как прочитает, с паузой или нет.
"Делается все, чтобы через взвинчивание напряженности вокруг межнациональных отношений, в связи с разгромом и т.д., сорвать поездку". Можно заменить :"Делается все, чтобы через взвинчивание напряженности вокруг межнациональных отношений, так как имели место разгром и т.д., сорвать поездку." Возможна замена - ставим запятые.